# Web3j listening to events

Tags: events, web3j

I'm tinkering with web3j and most of the things that I want to do succeed, however I seem to not be able to listen to events.

I've extended the ballot.sol contract you get with remix by adding an event VoteEnded, which is fired when a call is made to winningProposal and that works in the Remix JavaScript VM.

```
...
event VoteEnded();
...

function winningProposal() constant returns (uint8 winningProposal) {
    uint256 winningVoteCount = 0;
    for (uint8 proposal = 0; proposal < proposals.length; proposal++)
        if (proposals[proposal].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
            winningVoteCount = proposals[proposal].voteCount;
            winningProposal = proposal;
        }
    VoteEnded();
}
...
```

I am able to deploy this contract and vote etc. in Web3j. Then I added a filter to listen to VoteEnded. I did it like:

```
    EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contract.getContractAddress());
    web3.ethLogObservable(filter).subscribe(new Action1<Log>() {
        @Override    
        public void call(Log log) {
            System.out.println("log.toString(): " +  log.toString());
        }
    });
```

Which I found here: [A problem with filters and events (web3j/TestRPC). SOS! ;)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15824/a-problem-with-filters-and-events-web3j-testrpc-sos)

However this doesn't print anything at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is old, but providing an answer here as I came across this issue and couldn't find a solution elsewhere...

This appears to be a bug in Web3j that occurs when you pass in the contract address as part of your filter.

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contract.getContractAddress());
```

does not work, but

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contract.getContractAddress().substring(2));
```

does. It appears '0x' is being inserted at the beginning of the string when the filter is applied. Passing in the substring with the '0x' trimmed causes it to work.

(See also [Contract Address Must Be Trimmed In EthFilter](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/405))

Comment: Wasted hours over this one, you just saved me a few more, thanks

Comment: OUTDATED, address without Ox will give `org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.FilterException: Invalid request: invalid argument 0: invalid address at index 0: hex string without 0x prefix`

Answer (score 1):

Just did this recently, but I think this only works for events displayed at the time that your web page is open not from all blocks:

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/100/Solidity-Events-Tutorial---Using-Web3.js-to-Listen-for-Smart-Contract-Events

```
   var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract(YOUR ABI);

   var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS');

   var instructorEvent = Coursetro.Instructor();
   instructorEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
            {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $("#instructor").html(result.args.name + ' (' + result.args.age + ' years old)');
            } else {
                $("#loader").hide();
                console.log(error);
            }
    });
```