# Subscribing to event using web3j (2018)

Tags: truffle, events, web3j

I'm trying to subscribe to a smart contract event from my java app using [web3j](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/web3j/latest/web3j.pdf).

I deployed my contract to truffle, here it is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MyContract {

  string message;
  event MyEvent(address contractAddress, string message);


  constructor() public {
    message = "I'm ready!";
  }

  function setGreetings(string _message) public {
    message = _message;
  }

  function getGreetings() public view returns (string) {
    return message;
  }

  function triggetEvent() public {
    MyEvent(address(this), message);
  }

}
```

In my java app I'm subscribing to this event:

```
web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:9545/"));
Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
MyContract myContract = MyContract.load(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, web3, credentials, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, myContract.getContractAddress());
String encodedEventSignature = EventEncoder.encode(MyContract.MYEVENT_EVENT);
filter.addSingleTopic(encodedEventSignature);
log.info("subscribing to event with filter");
web3.ethLogObservable(filter).subscribe(eventString -> log.info("event string={}", eventString.toString()));
```

Where `MyContract.MYEVENT_EVENT` looks like this:

```
public static final Event MYEVENT_EVENT = new Event("MyEvent", 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(),
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>() {}, new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}));
```

Now I'm calling the `triggetEvent()` method from truffle console, the method runs but my java app prints nothing.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one solved it:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/41606/37689

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, greetingsContract.getContractAddress().substring(2));
```

Notice the `.substring(2)`