# Recover solidity funcion event in web3j

Tags: events, web3j

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, userContract.getContractAddress().substring(2));
```

I am trying to recover the event response that a solidity smart-contract return me. Searching in the web I find [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16697/web3j-listening-to-events) post. And works, but the problem is that I dont now what method I have to call to return just the string that de contract send me.

Something like:

```
System.out.println(filter.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, let's start from scratch.

Let's say you have a very simple contract which increments and decrements a counter deployed to the address `CONTRACT_X`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Counter {
    int counter; // Global state

    event CounterIncremented(address indexed _by, int _newValue);
    event CounterDecremented(address indexed _by, int _newValue);

    function increment(int _value) public {
        counter = counter + _value;
        emit CounterIncremented(msg.sender, counter);
    }

    function deincrement(int _value) public {
        counter = counter - _value;
        emit CounterDecremented(msg.sender, counter);
    }
}
```

**i. Event definition hash**

First you have to define each event (definition) in order to calculate the unique hash that represent this event on the network.

```
// Definition of event CounterIncremented(address indexed _by, int _newValue)
public static final Event INCREMENT_EVENT = new Event("CounterIncremented", 
    Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Int>(false) {}}));

// Definition of event CounterDecremented(address indexed _by, int _newValue)
public static final Event DECREMENT_EVENT = new Event("CounterDecremented", 
    Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Int>(false) {}}));
```

Then to calculate the hash of the event, you only need to do:

```
private static final String INCREMENT_EVENT_HASH = EventEncoder.encode(INCREMENT_EVENT);

private static final String DECREMENT_EVENT_HASH = EventEncoder.encode(DECREMENT_EVENT);
```

**ii. Filter**

Before subscribing to event, it is possible apply filters because by definition, the Ethereum events log (all events of all smart contracts of the network) can be query.

- Filter by Block range and Smart Contract

Return all the events of different types for the smart contract `CONTRACT_X`. In our case, we will get `CounterIncremented` and `CounterDecremented` events.

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, // From block 0
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,  // To last block
    CONTRACT_X); // Unique Smart Contract

EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, // only the latest block  
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,  // 
    CONTRACT_X); // Unique Smart Contract

EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.valueOf("2222"), // From block no 2222
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,  // To latest
    Arrays.asList(address1, address2, address3)); // List of Smart Contracts
```

*LATEST means you will pull the events coming in during the subscription*.

- Filter by events

If you want to filter by event type, for example to only get the `CounterIncremented` event, you can use the property `addSingleTopic`

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, // From block 0 
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,  // To latest
    CONTRACT_X) // Unique Smart Contract
.addSingleTopic(INCREMENT_EVENT_HASH);
```

- Filter by event parameters

Finally, you might want to filter by event parameters, for instance all the `CounterIncremented` events triggered by a given address (filter by parameter `_by` of the `CounterIncremented` event)

```
EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(
    DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, // From block 0
    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST,  // To latest
    CONTRACT_X) // Unique Smart Contract
.addSingleTopic(INCREMENT_EVENT_HASH)
.addOptionalTopic("0xdDd6427Aaf3766DC97A9cA9deDD3e7911b085B6B");
```

*Event parameter filter only applied for 'indexed' parameters.*

**iii. Subscribe to the events**

Finally, the last step consists in subscribing for events to the node:

```
web3.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(event -> { 
    event.getAddress(); // Smart contract address
    event.getBlockNumber(); // Block number
    event.getTransactionHash(); // Transaction that emitted the event
    event.getTopics().get(0); // Event hash
    event.getTopics().get(1-n); // Event parameter (1) _by, (2) _value
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, Thx;