# Error when starting testRPC

Tags: testrpc, nodes

I get this error when testrpc is launched. Somebody know how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: your error screenshot is unavailable

Comment: I get FilterSubprovider - no filter with that id: 0x01

Comment: Are you using any app that may try to connect to blockchain node like Mist or Metamask? Can you try to restart the computer and run testRPC again without any other apps running in the background?

Comment: check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15824/a-problem-with-filters-and-events-web3j-testrpc-sos

Comment: I waited like 5 minutes and then started successfully testrpc again. I have Metamask Chrome extension, but this seems not to be the issue.